# How to force wso2 api manager keymanager component using http?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Currently in the gateway configuration I have to set the protocol to https like:

```
<ServerURL>https://10.130.10.110:9443/services/</ServerURL>
```

10.130.10.110:9443 is the https end point of the keymanager. If I switch to the http end point, the token validation will fail.

I searched all the WSO2 AM document and all the config sample are pointing to keymanager using https. It looks like the key manager only supports https, is it possible to change it to http? Because all the servers are deployed inside one VPC, there is no need to use http. The https is too heavy and the overall API gateway performance doesn't look good.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out myself. There are two places needing to be changed:
1. There is a services.xml file under META-INFO in apimgt.keymgt. Add <transport>http</transport> to all the entries.
2. In APIManagerConfiguration.java, change the hard coded 'String serviceUrl = "https://" + ....'  to the protocol prefix.